Applying Dynkin's $\pi$-system lemma for almost sure equivalence of random variables
Show that given a $\pi$-system $P$ such that $\sigma(P)=\mathcal{F}$ and two random variables $X$ and $Y$ in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, if for any $A\in P$, $$\mathbb{E}(X 1_A)=\mathbb{E}(Y1_A)$$ then $X=Y$ almost surely.
To prove this, we must show that this holds for a minimal $\lambda$-system containing $P$, as this then yields the minimal $\sigma$-algebra of $P$. Assume that we've already show that the above equality holds for any $A, B\in P$ where $A\subset B$. It remains to show that for any increasing $A_n\in P$, the equality holds for $\cup_{n\geq 1}A$. I just want to double-check if the following approach is correct.
See that by Monotone Convergence Theorem (bounded by $\mathbb{E}(X)$), $$\mathbb{E}(X1_{\cup A_n})=\lim\mathbb{E}(X1_{A_n})=\mathbb{E}(X\lim1_{A_n})=\mathbb{E}(Y\lim1_{A_n})$$
Please let me know if I'm missing anything!

What you are trying to show is false. Take for example $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ a standard one-dimensional random variable and $Y:= -X$. Then almost surely $X \neq Y$. If $$\mathbb{E}(X 1_A)=\mathbb{E}(Y1_A),$$ for any $A$ in a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{F}$, then $X$ and $Y$ are equal in law but not almost surely.

@Shiva the result is well known. See the link provided and e.g. Schilling 11.7.(i) p. 92
